# Django STATIC not working when special characters in path

Tags: django

I am using STATIC to be able to call my css and js files in my templates. But i noticed every time there is a character like a space or a dash or some other special character it converts it to url and then it doesn't find the file

for example, i have the following css

```
static/
  css/
    template-style-min.css
```

no in my template when i call it like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/template-style-min.css' %}">
```

I keep getting a 404 on it, and i see in the logs its trying to call it like this

"GET /static/css/template-style-min.css%3Fv%3D1.0.0 HTTP/1.1" 404 1892

Not sure why it keeps adding that to the end of the css file. Can't figure it out.

Also if it type the url for that directly in the browser i can get to it no problem

Comment: It's a `?v=1.0.0` produced by additional package or your own code. Such versioning is used to avoid caching problems.